# Date only comparison without time using JPA named query

Tags: date, jpa, date-comparison

My database has a column that's `DATE`.

When generated the entity, it created a `Timestamp` field in the entity class.

```
@Column(name="MY_DATE")
private Timestamp myDate;
```

My incoming object is a `java.util.Date` object. `startDate` and `endDate`.

I need to write a JPA query that will fetch the records that has `my_date` between `startDate` and `endDate`. It is taking time into consideration.

Query condition

```
o.myDate >=:inputDate AND o.myDate <=:inputDate
```

Comment: So, what's exactly your problem? It would help if you submit the whole query and the error you are getting when executing it (if there's one!)

Comment: The query is using the time into consideration. how do I just compare date?

Comment: Oh I see... Have you tried the DATE function cast? DATE(o.myDate) >=:inputDate AND DATE(o.myDate) <=:inputDate. You should also make sure that your parameters are not using time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your entity code auto-generated? Maybe you should try updating your generated Entity code. Change the type of `myDate` field to `Date` instead of `java.sql.Timestamp`. Then annotate it with `@Temporal` and specify `DATE` as the type, as shown in the code below:

```
@Column(name="MY_DATE")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date myDate;
```

In your query, you can use `BETWEEN` instead of comparison operators:

```
o.myDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate
```